# \smile underneath the exponent

Tags: math-mode, positioning

I'd like to write a formula where there is a `$\smile$` underneath the exponent.

Like in this example which works fine:

```
 $2^{\overset{\text{blabla}}{\smile}}$
```

But when I want to replace the blabla by a mathematical symbol like `$\omega$` it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no problem. A minimal (non-)working example, maybe?

Comment: `$2^{\overset{\omega}{\smile}}$` ought to work.

Comment: Inside `\text{}` you can use `\ensuremath{\omega}`, but as egreg showed, do that in this example is obviously meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Aaah that question was not worth asking!

```
$2^{\overset{\text{blabla}}{\smile}}$
```

should not work because inside the text brackets it should be in mathmode.

Simple as that. Sorry for bothering...

Comment: Move to delete.  (This must be a super power I haven't gained yet.)